# Как получить CSS из SASS?

Tags: css, phpstorm, sass, less, webstorm

Настраиваю file watcher. Сохраняю main.sass и почему-то создается файл с данным содержимом:

```
write main.css
write main.css.map
```

А как получить CSS код через File watcher WebStorm
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какие настройки?

Comment: Это file watcher конкретной среды? Какую реализацию Sass используете -- рубишную или libsass? Какие настройки указали? Укажите эти сведения в вопросе.

Comment: Нужно в настройках SASS watchers указать путь к обработчику правильный

Comment: Долго пользовался watcher'ом PHPStorm'а для компиляции sass, позже пересел на сборщик проекта (gulp) - он мне понравился больше, возвращаться к watcher'ам нет желания, считаю устаревшей фичей.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не понял в чем именно была проблема, но теперь всё работает с данными настройками:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1):

можно не привязываться к определенной среде 
а использовать отдельный компилятор
например http://koala-app.com/

компилит все :)

Comment: какая то третья нога....даже не костыль